# What is difference using link in function php?

Tags: php

I have a function:

```
$array_numbers = [];
function uniqueNumber(& $array_numbers, $from, $to) {
    $number = rand($from, $to); 
    if (!in_array($number, $array_numbers)) {
        $array_numbers[] = $number;
    } else { 
        uniqueNumber($array_numbers, $from, $to); 
    }
}
```

What is reason to use link `& $array_numbers` in parameter's function?

Result will be the same in pass array `$array_numbers` without link

Comment: Your function __does not__ return any result.

Comment: @u_mulder Which is probably why `&` is used.

Comment: It's called "reference" and it's explained here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Function can not return value, is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use link then array will change outside function

```
$array_numbers = [];
function uniqueNumber(&$array_numbers) {
    $array_numbers[] = 1;
}
```

$array_numbers will be contains [1]

---

```
$array_numbers = [];
function uniqueNumber($array_numbers) {
    $array_numbers[] = 1;
}
```

$array_numbers will be empty []